# How to read data from NSInputStream explicitly in swift?

Tags: sockets, swift, nsstream, nsinputstream, nsoutputstream

I am using a socket connect in my application.

Here's my `SocketConnection.swift`

```
    init(host: String, port:UInt32){
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.status = false
        output = ""
        super.init()
    }

    func stream(aStream: NSStream, handleEvent aStreamEvent: NSStreamEvent) {
        switch aStreamEvent {

        case NSStreamEvent.OpenCompleted:
            break

        case NSStreamEvent.HasBytesAvailable:

            break

        case NSStreamEvent.HasSpaceAvailable:
            break

        case NSStreamEvent.EndEncountered:

//            aStream.close()
            aStream.removeFromRunLoop(NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop(), forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)
            break

        case NSStreamEvent.None:

            break

        case NSStreamEvent.ErrorOccurred:

            break

        default:
            println("# something weird happend")
            break
        }
    }

    func connect() {
        println("# connecting to \(host):\(port)")
        var cfReadStream : Unmanaged<CFReadStream>?
        var cfWriteStream : Unmanaged<CFWriteStream>?

        CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(kCFAllocatorDefault, host, port, &cfReadStream, &cfWriteStream)
        inputStream = cfReadStream!.takeRetainedValue()
        outputStream = cfWriteStream!.takeRetainedValue()

        inputStream!.delegate = self
        outputStream!.delegate = self

        inputStream!.scheduleInRunLoop(NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop(), forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)
        outputStream!.scheduleInRunLoop(NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop(), forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)

        inputStream!.open()
        outputStream!.open()
    }


    func read(){  
        var buffer = [UInt8](count: bufferSize, repeatedValue: 0)
        output = ""
        while (self.inputStream!.hasBytesAvailable){
            var bytesRead: Int = inputStream!.read(&buffer, maxLength: buffer.count)
            if bytesRead >= 0 {
                output += NSString(bytes: UnsafePointer(buffer), length: bytesRead, encoding: encoding)! as String
            } else {
                println("# error")
            }
            println("> \(output)")
        }
    }

    func send(message:String){        
            let data:NSData = message.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!
            let bytesWritten = self.outputStream!.write(UnsafePointer(data.bytes), maxLength: data.length)
            println("< send to \(host)")

    }
```

In my `ViewController.swift`,
I am connecting to the server like this

```
var socketConnection = SocketConnection(host: _ip, port: _port) 
socketConnection.connect() 
socketConnection.send(urlString) 
socketConnection.read()
```

Now I can send my url string via socket but when I am reading explicitly I am not getting the data from the server if I call the same read function from the `NSStreamEvent.HasBytesAvailable` case it printing the server response.. but how can I trigger the event queue?

I want to call this `socketConnection.read()` explicitly.. How can I do that?

After 2 sec of connection, its closes the connection channel, I want to keep alive my connection until I close.

Help me out from this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Don't schedule your stream if you want to read explicitly. But it may result blocking main thread.

Answer (score 1):

Change your read() as below and then call read() func in case NSStreamEvent.HasBytesAvailable:

```
private func read(stream: InputStream) {
    let maxReadLength = 1024
    let buffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: maxReadLength)
    while stream.hasBytesAvailable {
        let numberOfBytesRead = inputStream?.read(buffer, maxLength: maxReadLength)

        if numberOfBytesRead! < 0 {
            if let _ = inputStream?.streamError {
                break
            }
        }

        if let message = processedMessageString(buffer: buffer, length: numberOfBytesRead!) {
            delegate?.receivedMessage(message: message)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to call read functionality explicitly. Change your read func as below and call in case case Stream.Event.hasBytesAvailable:.

```
func read(stream: InputStream) {
let maxReadLength = 1024
var buffer = [uint8](repeating: 0, count: maxReadLength)
while stream.hasBytesAvailable {
    let numberOfBytesRead : Int = stream.read(&buffer, maxLength: maxReadLength)
    if numberOfBytesRead < 0 {
        if let _ = stream.streamError {
            break
        }
    }

    if let message = processedMessageString(buffer: buffer, length: numberOfBytesRead) {
        delegate?.receivedMessage(message: message)
    }
}}
```

If you want to call read() explicitly then you need to pass the stream as parameters and call the read function in ViewController class—

```
socketConnection.read(stream)
```